How to reset auto increment in symfony?
I've a Boat class for entity properties, new boat is added by a form (BoatAdType), here's my function of my controller :
#[Route('/new-ad', name: 'app_new_ad')]
    public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {

        $boatAd = new Boat();
        $form = $this->createForm(BoatAdType::class, $boatAd);
        Clock::set(new MockClock());
        $clock = Clock::get();
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $boatAd = $form->getData();
            $boatAd->setDateCreation($clock->now());
            $boatAd->setFKBoatUser($user);
            $entityManager->persist($boatAd);
            $entityManager->flush();
            // $posted = $this->generateUrl('app_ad_post_success'); not the most important subject, I comment it because it doesn't work
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_ad_post_success');
        }

        return $this->render('pages/boat_ad_form/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

I want to reset AUTO_INCREMENT after deleting rows in a table to avoid a gap between id values.
For that, I found this SQL query here :
ALTER TABLE sales_data AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
I also see this command (answer is for postgreSQL but I can use it for me table in MySQL, I didn't know which is better, if there is one) :
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY;
I saw we can create function inside BoatRepository to operate this query, like symfony docs says it. I tried to write one :
public function startFollowingCurrentOrder() {
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

        $sql = '
            ALTER TABLE boat AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
            ';
        return $conn->executeQuery($sql);
    }

I though import it in my form just before the return stament in index(), it is right ? And is this process correct ?

Don't do it. Treat the id as just some unique number and never rely on it being ordered or whatever. If you really need a value that reflects some particular order then add a column just for it. There are a gazillion sql articles explaining this sort of thing.

Okay, very well. No, the order will be managed by the creation datetime anyway.

What I wanted was to reset the id counter to 0 after my tests

If you are doing that sort of testing then it is best to simply drop and restore the entire database. Selective resetting just causes even more problems.
